# Get current user role in Moodle using MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, moodle, roles

I **only** have an access to Moodle **database** and **tables**. How do I get what **current** roles user has, using  `role id` and `user id`?
I have the following code but it only shows the latest role assignment:

```
//Get user id
$rowSQL = "SELECT id FROM mdl_user WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $linkMDL->prepare($rowSQL);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$userid = $stmt->get_result();
$userid = $userid->fetch_row();
$userid = $userid[0];
echo json_encode($userid);
$stmt->close;
//Check user role in Moodle by user id
$rowSQL = "SELECT roleid FROM mdl_role_assignments WHERE timemodified = (SELECT MAX(timemodified) FROM mdl_role_assignments WHERE userid=?)";
$stmt = $linkMDL->prepare($rowSQL);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$roleid = $stmt->get_result();
$roleid = $roleid->fetch_row();
$roleid = $roleid[0];
echo json_encode($roleid);
$stmt->close;
```

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't really make sense from a Moodle perspective. Roles only make sense for a particular context within Moodle (e.g. for a particular course or course category, or even for a particular activity within a course). So, you need to first determine the id of the relevant area within Moodle you want to check, then get the relevant context id from the context table, then look for a role assignment with that userid, roleid and context id.

Comment: @davosmith oh i get it now